# Multiply rows starting by the same string in two different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes with the following structure:

```
hheuwh_df
Out[8]: 
             2017          2018
Geo                            
AT    2010.995000   1970.876944
BE    5432.053611   5457.952778
BG     105.436667    125.081944
CZ    5268.712500   5120.062222
DE   49986.276111  53605.346667
DK    1795.833333   1955.555556
EE      82.849167     82.500000
EL     165.879722    469.332500
ES   13977.728056  13635.448611
FI      61.250000     59.000000
FR   14052.315278  13945.601389
HR    1037.459167   1010.527500
HU    3441.843611   3336.155278
IE    1771.082500   1832.023333
IT   29621.374444  29911.172778
LT     196.750000    207.000000
LU     304.662222    250.367778
LV     244.393889    261.590833
NL   16704.166667  16704.166667
PL   10973.000000  10973.000000
PT    1801.363056   1961.978333
RO    6404.175000   6649.063333
SE      79.750000     72.000000
SI     265.800000    259.135556
SK    1635.002500   1598.825000
    
temp
Out[9]: 
      Percentage2017  Percentage2018
Geo                                 
AT11        0.033278        0.033175
AT12        0.189876        0.189369
AT13        0.212882        0.214092
AT21        0.063956        0.063578
AT22        0.141037        0.140578
             ...             ...
SI04        0.471823        0.472772
SK01        0.118096        0.119571
SK02        0.336823        0.335915
SK03        0.246955        0.246331
SK04        0.298125        0.298182

[242 rows x 2 columns]
```

I would like to multiply the values that start by same characters in the indexes of both dataframes.
That is, for each column multiply AT1, AT2, AT3 by AT, FR1, FR5 and FR7 by FR, and so on. What would be the best way to achieve this, storing the results either in the second dataframe or in a new dataframe? Thank you in advance.

Comment: it is `str` or `int` ?

Comment: I'm getting an error:

`The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\sand_jv\Desktop\Eurostat Datasets\Input_datasets.py", line 109, in <module>
    print (type(hheuwh_df[0]))

  File "C:\Users\sand_jv\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2902, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

  File "C:\Users\sand_jv\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2897, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err

KeyError: 0`

Comment: Sorry, `print (type(hheuwh_df.columns[0]))`

Comment: It's an int:
`type(hheuwh_df.columns[0])
Out[18]: int`

Comment: Thank you, can you test `EDIT` in answer?

Comment: I'm getting a length mismatch error. I'll check out the datasets.

`ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected 240 rows, received array of length 242`

Comment: How wokring if remove `.set_index(temp.index)` ?

Comment: I found the problem. The second dataset contained data for countries with codes that were not present in the original one. Not it's working perfectly. Thanks a lot for your time and your help! :)

Comment: Thanks, glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it suits you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all values is necessary match by first 2 letters select it in `rename`, multiple and last set same values like original:

```
df = df.rename(lambda x: x[:2]).mul(df2).set_index(df.index)
print (df)
     1995  1996
AT1     3    18
AT2     5     9
AT3     2     3
FR1     2     4
FR5     4     4
FR7    14    32
```

If need match values without numbers use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) working with regex:

```
df1 = df.copy()
df1.index = df1.index.str.replace('\d', '')
df1 = df1.mul(df2).set_index(df.index)
print (df1)
     1995  1996
AT1     3    18
AT2     5     9
AT3     2     3
FR1     2     4
FR5     4     4
FR7    14    32
```

Or `rename`:

```
import re
df = df.rename(lambda x: re.sub('\d','', x)).mul(df2).set_index(df.index)
print (df)
     1995  1996
AT1     3    18
AT2     5     9
AT3     2     3
FR1     2     4
FR5     4     4
FR7    14    32
```

EDIT:

If values of column in `hheuwh_df` are integers also convert last 4 values of columns to years in inetegers and also remove only missing values in rows:

```
print (type(hheuwh_df.columns[0]))
int

df = (temp.rename(index=lambda x: x[:2], 
                 columns=lambda x: int(x[-4:]))
          .mul(hheuwh_df)
          .dropna(how='all')
          .set_index(temp.index))
print (df)

            2017        2018
Geo                         
AT11   66.921892   65.383843
AT12  381.839687  373.222996
AT13  428.104638  421.948987
AT21  128.615196  125.304414
AT22  283.624702  277.061939
SI04  125.410553  122.512035
SK01  193.087255  191.173104
SK02  550.706447  537.069300
SK03  403.772042  393.840161
SK04  487.435120  476.740836
```

Comment: Hey jezrael, thanks for your answer. The dataframes I used were an example of what I'm trying to do, but unfortunately when I do the same with my original data, I get nan values.
Both datasets contain float64 values. Any idea where the problem may be? I'll add the datasets in a comment below.

Comment: @JavierSando - Is possible see if same columns names? `print (df.columns)` vs `print (df2.columns)` ? If use `rename` like `print (df.rename(lambda x: x[:2]).index)` then values of index matching with `print (df2.index)` ?